# How to use button onClick in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs. I am trying to make a duplicate of my existing website into reactjs with the help of components. I have some html code which triggers javascript function to do the action. How can I change it into reactjs. The following is the code.

HTML:
I have written all this HTML code in the render function of reactjs classes.

```
class Index extends Component {
  render() {
return(
                  <div className="tabs-content">
                    <div id="login-tab-content" className="active">
                      <iframe
                        align="left"
                        frameBorder="0"
                        scrolling="no"
                        width="300"
                        height="180"
                        name="dc_login_iframe"
                        id="dc_login_iframe"
                        src="https://login.doccheck.com/code/12345/de/m_red//"
                      >
                        <a
                          href="https://login.doccheck.com/code/12345/de/m_red/"
                          target="_blank"
                        >
                          LOGIN
                        </a>
                      </iframe>
                    </div>

                    <div className="signup-tab-content">
                      <form className="signup-form" action="" method="post">
                        <label>
                          <input
                            type="radio"
                            name="test"
                            value="small"
                            checked
                          />
                        </label>
                        <label>
                          <input type="radio" name="test" value="big" />
                        </label>
                        <input
                          type="submit"
                          className="button"
                          value="Sign Up"
                        />
                      </form>
                    </div>
                  </div>
);}
```

The JS is as follows
Javascript:

```
// LOGIN TABS
$(function() {
  var tab = $(".tabs h3 a");
  tab.on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    tab.removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
    tab_content = $(this).attr("href");
    $('div[id$="tab-content"]').removeClass("active");
    $(tab_content).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

As I already put my html code in render function, where should I put JS code?

Comment: Please [see this](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html).

Comment: I already had. That is why I am here. I am new to react and therefore I can't understand how can I change the active state on one class.

Comment: Changing state? Again, it is already in documents. Before trying to convert anything into React at least you should read its official documentation. Nobody can suggest anything unless you show some code how you try it and where you stuck. You can keep a state for active items and change the classes conditionally according to this state. Don't try to think as you do in Jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onClick={this.clicked.bind(this)}` attribute on the html element inside the render method.

Then in your class Index create a new method called `clicked` with the logic of your js file